# how to select VOD server

Tags: server, cloud, hosting, cdn, vod

I am developing a video project on laravel and database is mysql.
Where user can login and upload their videos. And all the users can watch the video. Everything is perfect. But My client asking me to upload videos on the  VOD server and also integrate CDN. Below is client's need:

```
I want to know please and be sure that you will work on the infrastructure of our platform to be able to integrate 'Video-On-Demand" (VOD) and "Content Delivery Network (CDN)" service from cloud services providers. We want that our platform be able to be integrated with CDN VOD and be able in the future to handle monetization models such as:

i- Monetizing with Ads (AVOD),  ii- Monetizing with Pay-Per-View (TVOD) and iii. Monetizing with Subscriptions (SVOD)
```

I didn't work on VOD server before and I am very confused how to select any good server. Here are few queries of mine:

```
1- Is VOD server and cloud server are different?
2- If I go with any VOD server then Do I have to upload the entire project to VOD server?
3- OR Do I have to upload the entire project to any other server except VOD and only videos will be uploaded on VOD server by any API?
4- How can I select configurations for any VOD server like: Memory, CPU and what else to handle the traffic?
5- Which VOD server will be good. I have checked few companies but I'm confused:

A) https://aws.amazon.com/s3/
B)- https://www.muvi.com/
C)- https://bunny.net/
D)- https://vimeo.com/
```

So far, I have worked on shared hosting only. Please guide me.
Thankyou in advance.